# How can i detect if user is signed in anonumously with firebase auth?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase auth for my login system and detect if user is signed in anonumously, how could i do it?
I know that with facebook is

```
for (UserInfo user: FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getProviderData()) { if (user.getProviderId().equals("facebook.com")) { System.out.println("User is signed in with Facebook"); } }
```

But since there is no url to check I don't know if this is possible.
I would appreciate any help

Comment: You can refer https://github.com/surajmakhija07/FirebaseAnonymousAuthentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [isAnonymous()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#isAnonymous()) method on FirebaseUser.

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user.isAnonymous()) {
    // ...
}
```